# React: avoid rendering component's root DOM element if DOM children are empty

Tags: reactjs

I have a React component which receives `children`, wrapping them in a DOM element:

```
const MyComponent = ({ children }) => <div>{children}</div>;
```

When `children` resolves to 0 DOM nodes, I want to skip rendering the container DOM element (`div` in this example).

(This is because the container DOM element may contribute semantics or styles which we don't want/need if the element is going to be empty.)

E.g.

```
const MySubComponent = () => null;

declare const maybeChild: string | undefined;
const el = <MySubComponent />;

const el = (
  <MyComponent>
    {maybeChild}
    {el}
  </MyComponent>
)
```

In this example, the resulting DOM would be `<div></div>`.

Presumably I should do this by counting the number of *DOM* children inside `MyComponent` (using this as a condition for what to render), but there doesn't seem to be an easy way to do this. (The [`React.Children` API](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren) refers to the children in the React node tree, rather than the DOM, so this doesn't seem to be helpful in this case.)

One solution I'm aware of is to ensure a 1:1 mapping of React nodes to DOM nodes. However this seems to be impractical because components often have rendering conditions inside of them.

Comment: what about returning null before rendering your component?

Comment: The problem is that even if all the children render down to nothing, the React elements still exist and could update to render something without re-rendering the parent.

Comment: There's no straightforward way to do this. You will need to render chidren and make sure there are DOM elements. Why is empty div a problem? This could be XY problem.

Comment: @estus I mentioned in my question why this is a problem—because the empty element may contribute styles (e.g. spacing, border) or semantics (e.g. a button), which might not make sense if the component's children resolve to nothing.

Comment: @OliverJosephAsh That's what I meant by XY problem. Use :empty for styles. That's much more straightforward than accessing DOM directly.

Comment: Reference related to @estus's comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty. The styles for your div could be done using `:not(:empty)`.

Comment: This seems like a case of the control being in the wrong place. Whatever is controlling whether or not the sub-component renders anything, could be moved higher up in the element hierarchy so that you just avoid rendering the parent when it isn't needed. It is difficult to give better guidance without knowing more about what the sub-component is doing.

Comment: `:empty` would help avoid redundant styling, but we still have the issue of semantics and a11y. We should only render what is needed.
@RyanCogswell Re. moving conditional renders from the inside of components to the outside (which I think is what you're suggesting), I had thought that, but that breaks encapsulation.

Comment: I wouldn't expect reworking this to break encapsulation -- it would shift how the responsibilities are organized. Some sort of data drives whether the sub-component renders anything. That data should also determine whether the parent is rendered. Presumably the sub-component is both getting the data and rendering. If the sub-component becomes purely presentational, you could wrap the current parent in something that gets the data, decides whether rendering is necessary and, if so, then passes the data to the sub-component.

Answer (score 5):

This problem feels like it should be re-engineered. I know this is not a satisfactory solution, but children could contain literally hundreds of DOM nodes and could be intense in their depth. It does not feel prudent to embark on this. Also, there should be a general hesitation when exposing implementation details of a child to its parent. If you truly wanted to do this i would look towards [React refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html), but they're only available post initial render.

Answer (score -1):

You should use [React.Fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) and check for children.

e.g.

```
const MyComponent = ({ children }) => <React.Fragment>
    {children ? 
        <div>{children}</div> 
        : 
        null
    }
</React.Fragment>;
```

*I noticed that you use typescript and I'm don't know much about typescript and how to do checking, but if you follow the logic, I think you can work it out using typescript

## Edit:

So what you need to do is check if the children is a valid React Element.

To check that you will need [React.isValidElement](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#isvalidelement)

And here is how you can check if it's valid or not

```
const MyComponent = ({ children }) => {
  let valid = true;
  if (Array.isArray(children)) {
    for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
      if (!isValidElement(children[i])) {
        valid = false;
      }
    }
  } else {
    valid = isValidElement(children);
  }
  if (valid) {
    return <div>{children}</div>;
  }
  return null;
};
```

I created a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wqm7kooo8) to check if works or not.

Using `React.isValidElement` you can do other checkings (maybe only rendering valid React Components)

And again, sorry for not giving the answer in typescript.

## Edit:

If this solution is still not satisfatory, because of elements that can render `null`, then you should take a look at lluisrojass explanation.

Comment: In my example above, `children` will be truthy, so this won't do the job unfortunately. Even if you `React.Children.count(children)`, it would be `2`.

Comment: @OliverJosephAsh just edit, now I think this solve your problem

Comment: `isValidElement` would still return `true` for a component that renders nothing. E.g. to follow my original example, `<MySubComponent />`

Comment: That is because rendering `null` is valid. So you want to render only html (or component) and not allowing it to render `null`?